# Creating table with limited number of rows

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to create table that have limited numbers of rows. 
For example if we try insert data into that table where rownumber is bigger than 2.000, that return some error or something.

How to manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach could be by creating a trigger to check the number of inserted rows; for example, say you have this table

```
create table notManyRows(n number)
```

and you want to limit the number of rows to 3, you can add a trigger like:

```
create or replace trigger notManyRowsTrg
after insert on notManyRows
declare
    vCheck number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into vCheck
    from notManyRows;
    --
    if vCheck > 3 then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'Too many rows in the table');
    end if;
end;
```

How it works:

```
SQL> insert into notManyRows values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into notManyRows values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into notManyRows values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into notManyRows values (1);
insert into notManyRows values (1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Too many rows in the table
ORA-06512: at "ALEK.NOTMANYROWSTRG", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ALEK.NOTMANYROWSTRG'


SQL>
```

Comment: Is it possible to create primary key, that will be auto increment from number 1 to the 2000?

Comment: It depends on your Oracle version. However, how could this prevent inserting rows? You would still need a trigger that checks if the PK value is greater than the limit; also, what if I delete all the rows with Ids in 1... 19999?

Comment: Thank You very much. When someove solve it, it looks very easy :)

Comment: Oracle version is 11g. I didn't think that deleting rows between 1 and 19999 could be a problem, totally forgot about that.  I just asking, that can clarify what is the best option. Someone with much more experience can have bigger picture than rocky like me. That's why I am asking :)